# log4j2 - RollingFileAppender - Invalid cross-device link

Tags: java, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I use log4j `2.8.1`
I have this `log4j2.xml` file

```
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyAppx" packages="">
<Appenders>      
    <RollingFile append="true" name="MyFile" fileName="/tmp/app.log" filePattern="/var/log/myLogs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} s7tcp     %-5level %-30notEmpty{[%marker]} - %msg%xEx - %class{36} %L %M%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO" includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

I do logging to `/tmp/app.log` and if the file gets bigger than `2MB` it should be moved to `/var/log/myLogs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log`

but I get this error Messages:

```
2017-04-03 10:30:00,874 Thread-3 ERROR Unable to move file /tmp/app.log to /var/log/myLogs/app-04-03-2017-19.log: java.nio.file.AtomicMoveNotSupportedException /tmp/app.log -> /var/log/myLogs/app-04-03-2017-19.log: Invalid cross-device link
2017-04-03 10:30:12,107 Thread-3 ERROR Unable to move file /tmp/app.log to /var/log/myLogs/app-04-03-2017-20.log: java.nio.file.AtomicMoveNotSupportedException /tmp/app.log -> /var/log/myLogs/app-04-03-2017-20.log: Invalid cross-device link
2017-04-03 10:30:23,396 Thread-3 ERROR Unable to move file /tmp/app.log to /var/log/myLogs/app-04-03-2017-20.log: java.nio.file.AtomicMoveNotSupportedException /tmp/app.log -> /var/log/myLogs/app-04-03-2017-20.log: Invalid cross-device link
2017-04-03 10:30:34,624 Thread-3 ERROR Unable to move file /tmp/app.log to /var/log/myLogs/app-04-03-2017-20.log: java.nio.file.AtomicMoveNotSupportedException /tmp/app.log -> /var/log/myLogs/app-04-03-2017-20.log: Invalid cross-device link
```

only the First file `-1.log` is actually created, all other files are created when I stop the java process!

If the path in `filePattern` is also on `/tmp/...` it works just fine!

Any Idea what the problem could be?

Comment: I think this is because /tmp/ and /var/log/ are on separate file systems. Does the same issue happen when fileName="" is also on /var/ ?